# Как программно изменить значение ключа, объявленного в resource dictionary

Tags: uwp

У меня в ресурсах объявлены два ключа:

```
<x:Double x:Key="LargerSize">20</x:Double>
<x:Double x:Key="BigSize">24</x:Double>
```

которые используются здесь:

```
<Style x:Key="baseTitleStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="/Assets/Fonts/Poppins-Regular.ttf#Poppins"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource LargerSize}" />
</Style>

<Style x:Key="CaptionStyle" TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource baseTitleStyle}">
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource BigSize}" />
</Style>
```

При программном изменении таким способом:

```
App.Current.Resources["LargerSize"] = 16d;
App.Current.Resources["BigSize"] = 18d;
```

приложение падает с исключением `System.Exception: "Разрушительный сбой (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил.
Добавил класс `FontSettings` со статичными полями:

```
public class FontSettings
{
    public static double TitleSize { get; }
    public static double CaptionSize { get; }

    static FontSettings()
    {
        FontSizeType fontSize = (FontSizeType)AppSettings.SelectedFontSize;
        switch (fontSize)
        {
            case FontSizeType.Small:
                TitleSize = 16d;
                CaptionSize = 18d;
                break;
            case FontSizeType.Medium:
                TitleSize = 18d;
                CaptionSize = 20d;
                break;
            case FontSizeType.Large:
                TitleSize = 20d;
                CaptionSize = 24d;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Статичные поля привязал к стилям в Resource Dictionary:

```
<local:FontSettings x:Key="FontSettings"/>

<Style x:Key="baseTitleStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="/Assets/Fonts/Poppins-Regular.ttf#Poppins"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource FontSettings}, Path=TitleSize}" />
</Style>

<Style x:Key="CaptionStyle" TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource baseTitleStyle}">
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource FontSettings}, Path=CaptionSize}" />
</Style>
```